# Externalizing constant strings in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am looking for a solution where I have couple of screens made in ExtJS and these screens have buttons and labels and I want to move these strings in a constants file and use the constants everywhere.

Something similar to a `final Constants` class in java where we declare the constant strings and then use it all around.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following

a. Create a js file (literals.js), which contains all the strings, like the following

```
function _literals() 
{
   this.Literal1 = "Defining literal";
}
var Literals = new _literals();
```

b. Add this file in the index.html
c. In your JavaScript code, you can use the literals as

```
text: Literals.Literal1
```